Designing a Kafka consumer that gets a high throughput of "redundant" events
Context:

We have 2 services - a user-facing API server and a background processing Kafka worker.
Both of these are hosted on AWS EKS, and we use AWS MSK for Kafka.
The job of the API server is to support user onboarding, authentication and other front-facing workflows. It also emits Kafka events for the different touchpoints of the user journey.
The job of the Kafka worker is to receive these events, and do some auxiliary operations, such as sending notifications or auto-update of certain entities based on conditions.
Both of these are 2 independent micro services with their own separate databases.

Problem:

The problem is that the upstream API server produces a lot of events (10-15rps) and only around 5-10% of the events are actually "useful" for the Kakfa worker.
This is primarily because the Kafka worker has a filtering logic in its DB that is used for checking whether the event is indeed processable or not.
This filtering logic is essentially checking a few other parameters of the customer, like payment status, billing info etc.
This then means that the Kafka worker needs to have a high partition and Kubernetes pod count, increasing our AWS bills (even though most events being processed are just discarded).

Possible solutions:

We can move the filtering logic to the API server, but the API server can't access other services' DBs.
We can keep a copy of the filter conditions in the API server's DB, and before sending the Kafka event, the API server can do this checking on its own. But obviously, this is data duplication and we now have a headache of how to sync any updates to the filter conditions between the 2 copies.
A couple of articles online talked about Kafka streams, but they can only filter on parameters within the message itself, while our use case is about accessing filter conditions stored in the DB.

I understand this is kind of an inherent problem with a message broadcasting system like Kafka, which simply sends generic messages "blindly", and any specific filtering needs to be done by the consumer.
But this is leading to unnecessarily high costs for running our infra and I wanted to know if there's any way to solve this. This should be a common problem in the industry, so I'm hoping this is a solved problem and someone can help us here.

"[T]he upstream API server produces a lot of events (5-6rps)" - What is rps? Records per second? This does not sound like a lot at all... If I were you I might be trying to increase processing throughput of the individual workers. E.g. Is there any unnecessary database locking that could be causing a bottleneck?

@PMah, yes it's records per second. Sorry, I had the wrong numbers. It's actually 10-15 rps. I've edited my question.
But yes, I agree it may not sound like a lot, but it does mean we have to run X workers, but in reality, we need only X/4 workers to process the "valid" events.

@PMah, to answer your question about bottlenecks...
There's no DB locking, but there are a lot of filter conditions. I think for every event, we check 10-15 different filter conditions, and these are scattered across 4-5 different tables. There are no locks involved in this process, but because of this scattered logic, the per-event-processing-time becomes slightly larger.

You want high throughput, but the problem why your consumer doesn't have the desired throughput is the latency of each individual operation. You can reduce this latency to effectively zero if the consumer processes multiple messages concurrently. For example, read a batch of up to N messages from the same partition and handle them in bulk, e.g. 1 thread per message or with bulk database queries. That will take only slightly longer than processing a single message. Reading the batch from a single partition makes it easier to understand offsets/commits for the consumer, but isn't essential.

You aren’t considering instead API server and Kafka worker deploy a lightweight filtering service to publish specific events. It will reduce scalability if you combine Kafka Streams

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

An additional service will to do the same job as final consumers and make same requests to DB. So the workload would be unchanged. However, it can use less RAM, which would make it cheaper. The answer is clear, if not very useful.
